# receiving input from webpage into a python program

Tags: php, python, html, apache

I am making a webpage in which there is a search box which has to take in a text input and it has to send this input as a input to the Python program. This program returns an text output which has to be rendered back on the webpage. The python program is done but not able to figure a way to **receive input from the browser** into Python. I have searched many other similar questions related to this and seen Youtube tutorials regarding CGI,django,PHP exec...etc,none of which have led to a conclusive solution.

I use Windows 10 running Apache 2.4 through XAMPP.

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: _"none of which have led to a conclusive solution"_ - Have you at least actually _tried_ something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to point your form action to a python route (method GET or POST as you want).
There are several libraries and methods to perform this stuff: bottle (good for py2.7), routes from pip and the best web development [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/)!

You will need integrate your python program with those new features and treat this like python back end of your web site.
See Flask

Comment: I actually think that the OP is building the site in PHP and just wants to use a Python script for the search feature. I'm not sure though, since the OP hasn't specified it clearly enough.

Comment: yes i am using the python for the search feature only precisely